# $\pi(x)\leq \frac x{f(x)}$ for some unbounded function $f(x)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

> Let $\pi(x)$  denote the number of primes $\le x$.  Can one prove 
>
> $$\pi(x)\leq \frac x{f(x)}$$
>
> for some  function $f(x)(x\gt0)$, and  $f(x)$ is unbounded?

Please **do not** refer to [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

From 1848 and 1850, Chebyshev proved that

$$\pi(x)\leq 1.1056\frac x{\log x}$$

Is there a possibile that the idea to apply elementary method to seek other unbounded function $f(x)$  different from $\log x$ such that $\pi(x)\leq \frac x{f(x)}$ ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean other than ones directly implied by Chebyshev (such as $\sqrt{\log x}$)?

Comment: Well I assume that someting like $\sqrt{\log x}$ is a valid answer if one can present a proof that is significantly simpler than a proof of Chebyshev's (or a similar) result.

Comment: @MatthewConroy   I only quote some facts. It will be better if someone  find function other than Chebyshev

Answer (score 2):

You can take $f(x) = \frac{x}{\pi(x)}$ and then prove that this function is unbounded. For that it is sufficient to prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{x} = 0$. This question has a great answer here:

[prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \pi(x)/x=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28540/prove-that-lim-x-to-infty-pix-x-0)

Comment: Interestingly, if you want to understand how large $f(x)$ is (even just any quantitative lower bound tending to infinity), then one seems to need Chebyshev's theorem somewhere in the proof; but just showing that it goes to infinity qualitatively just uses Euler's result that $\sum \frac1p$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Given $x$, let $g(x)$ denote the number of integers less than $x$ that are not divisible by any prime up to $\sqrt{\log x}$, say. Note that $\pi(x)\le g(x)$ always. It's possible, using inclusion/exclusion (the sieve of Eratosthenes), to show that $g(x) < x/f(x)$ where $f(x) = \delta\log\log x$ for some constant $\delta>0$. Look at the beginning of Chapter 3 of Montgomery/Vaughan's **Multiplicative Number Theory. I.** Note however that this approaches actually uses Chebyshev's theorem and its consequences (due to Mertens) as input.